# Socket.io v1.0: unknown transport

Tags: socket.io, php, node.js

Столкнулся такой проблемой. Для связи с сервером используется библиотека [ElephantIO](https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io/), который выполняет вот такую команды:

```
$client = new Client(new Version1X('http://'.core::$_config['socket']['server'].':'.core::$_config['socket']['port'].'/socket.io/?'.http_build_query($_ElephantIO)));
$client->initialize();

$client->emit('broadcast', ['foo' => 'bar']);

$client->close();
```

Однако запрос не удается из-за того, что сервер возвращает "transport unknown".

Comment: Покопался в коде движка и обнаружил, что скрипт выполняет два запроса: WebSocket и polling. При polling сервер выдает нормальный результат, но при использовании  websocket сервер выдает такую ошибку: 

    {"code":3,"message":"Bad request"}

Comment: Проблема решена.